# Assign default values while creating new Item

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

This question about Telerik MVC Grid.

I have two Grids with Master->Details relationship. These to grids are loaded using Ajax Binding. I want to create new Item in Details grid and pass ProductId field value from Master grid.
I have added property below but do not know how to get ProductId from Master grid. I have tried to pass value using ViewBag on Detail child loading it it seems ViewBag is not assigned then Ajax call is performed. Maybe someone know how to solve this problem?

```
Editable(editing => editing.DefaultDataItem(new UserViewModel { ProductId = ?????? })
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have Master Grid and Detail Grid,
and you want to create record in the Detail Grid ,
You should add JavaScript logic which uses the OnSave event of the Detail Grid to pass additional value to the server (it should be the selected record in the Master Grid).
Check the [documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-client-api-and-events.html#OnSave) there are examples.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using **client side template** for this?

```
Editable(editing => editing.DefaultDataItem(new UserViewModel { ProductId = <#= ProductId #> })
```

If you're using **Ajax binding**, you could also pass the parent's ID on insert:

```
dataBinding.Ajax().Insert("_Insert", "SubItem", new { productId= "<#= ProductId #>" }));
```

Don't forget to set your DataKey of the parent grid

```
.DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(c => c.Id))
```